# Unsupported Media Type" message: "Content type '' - but works in POSTMAN

Tags: reactjs, content-type, http-status-code-415

I have a problem. I try to call this `GET` method in `ReactJS`:

```js
const API_URL="http://****/sample/";
class Service{    
getKnjige(){
    const token = getToken();
    
    return axios.get(
        API_URL,
        {        
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
                 dataType: "json"
            } 
        });
}
```

I got this error:

> {timestamp: "2021-01-14T19:22:39.096+0000", status: 415, error: "Unsupported Media Type",…}
> error: "Unsupported Media Type"
> message: "Content type '' not supported"
> path: "/sample/"
> status: 415
> timestamp: "2021-01-14T19:22:39.096+0000"

However, when I call the method via `Postman`, it works with `Content-type: application/json`

Answer (score 0):

You're making a GET request.

There is no request body at all, let alone an XML request body.

Don't set a Content-Type on your request if you aren't **sending** content.

---

There's also no `dataType` request (or response) header in HTTP at all.

`dataType` is a configuration option for jQuery … which you aren't using.